# Natya mudras for maheshwara sutra

Tags: mudra, natya-shastra

I like to know natya mudras/Natya on for Maheshwara sutra

नृत्तावसाने नटराजराजो ननाद ढक्कां नवपञ्चवारम्।
उद्धर्त्तुकामः सनकादिसिद्धादिनेतद्विमर्शे शिवसूत्रजालम्॥